# Floating window with Tab Panel in ExtJs

Tags: extjs

I have below code and what I want to achieve is when a button is clicked. A Tab Panel should Open with various tab buttons. Here is my code but its not working.

```
showImageDetailsFloatingWindow: function (isShowHideImageDetailsAction) {
        this.showImageDetailsAction.setText(isShowHideImageDetailsAction ? 'Hide Details' : 'Show Image Details');
        this.showImageDetailsAction.setTooltip(isShowHideImageDetailsAction ? 'Hide Details' : 'Show Image details')
        if (!this.floatingImageDetailsToolBar) {
            //var floatingImageDetailsToolBar = new Ext.Window({
                var tabPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
                    itemId: 'tabPanel',
                    region: 'center',
                    enableTabScroll: true,
                    activeTab: 0,
                    defaults: {
                        layout: 'fit',
                        border: 'false'
                    },
                    layoutOnTabChange: true,
                    items: [{title: 'Hellow'}]
                });
            Ext.apply(config, {
                region: 'north',
                height: 460,
                split: true
            });
            this.formPanel = new Ext.FormPanel(config);
            this.winConfig = Ext.apply(this.winConfig, {
                layout: 'border',
                modal: 'false',
                defaults: {
                    border: false
                },
                items: [this.formPanel, tabPanel],
                listeners: {
                    beforeshow: function (window) {
                        var tab = window.getComponent('tabPanel');
                        tab.setActiveTab(0);
                    }
                },
            });
        

            this.floatingImageDetailsToolBar = floatingImageDetailsToolBar;
        };
        this.floatingImageDetailsToolBar.show();
        if (!isShowHideImageDetailsAction) {
            this.floatingImageDetailsToolBar.hide();
        }
    },
```

I tried using different format but still wont work. Someone help me to be able to display tabs in a floating window panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `this.winConfig` with:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
   title: 'Hello',
   height: 200,
   width: 400,
   layout: 'fit',
   items: [tabPanel]
}).show();
```

From the [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.window.Window.html)

Comment: The rest of the code looks fine?. Am new to Extjs

Comment: The function `showImageDetailsFloatingWindow` is overloaded: you can extract `tabPanel` and `formPanel` to the new Window. Leave `showImageDetailsFloatingWindow` just to show the new Window. No need to process multiple ifs: this fn should just display the new Window.

Comment: That suggestion is not working. When I run it displays nothing.

Comment: Also when I change to Ext.create is says that 'Ext.create' is not a function with this error. 
  Uncaught TypeError: Ext.create is not a function

Comment: Which version of Ext are you using? And classic or modern?

Comment: I am using Classic

Comment: Update your code in the example that you gave: Ext.create() is a core function of ExtJS